# XenServer Hotfix XS62ESP1005 - Which device drivers to update?

Tags: linux, xenserver

I am updating my XenServer 6.2 installation with all the latest hotfixes and according to the notes I need to update my device drivers before restarting the server. When I go to the page with the device drivers on (http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX140483) there are lots listed, do I need to update them all or is there a way I can check to see which ones I am using and just update those?

Edit: I ended up applying them all manually to just get it done. Would be interested to know a way though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to update all of them. Basically you need to know your HW, for example if you don't use a FC storage, you have no need to update the qlogic driver (most probably it's not even installed on your system). The other way around if you have an Intel network card then you need to upgrade the e1000 driver. You can check your HW from OS level with `lspci` also `lsmod` will give you the information about modules loaded(used) by kernel. This should give you some hints about any drivers to update before hot fix installation.

Comment: Many thanks, that makes life easier going forward.